# How to install apk file on the Xperia Android mobile

Tags: android

I want to test my build on my device. Please provide some tool/information regarding installation of application on device ?

thanks and regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your device with the PC, install the Android SDK (you should have that already) and than: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Open phone web-browser.
2. Enter url: file:///sdcard/[nameofyourapkfile].apk

No need for file browser programs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to install the apk file on the mobile without the need of any debug information you can simply upload the apk file (which is located in the `/bin` directory of your project) to a webspace and grab it with the mobile's browser (e.g. http://www.mywebspace.com/myapp.apk)

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy the apk to your phone - SD card or internal memory- and then click on it. This should install the apk in most devices, though some devices may block the installation of non-market apks.

Answer (score 0):

Or download SD Folder or something like that just type SD Folder into Googleplay and then youll be able to simply open apk files or Pics you couldnt access trough the office suit.